# What is the best framework with EJB, webservice?

Tags: jakarta-ee, frameworks, web

I'm starting to develop a web application which works with web-services and EJBs. 
What Java web framework should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Seam](http://seamframework.org/), it simplifies the development of Java web applications under Java EE, and it will work fine with web services, EJBs, etc.